# How to implement dynamic multi dimensional grid view(scroll view)?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, gridview

I need dynamic multi dimensional gird view. How to implement this design in the iPhone(like screenshot) ? The inner details are dynamic values.

Please give some sample source code for multi dimensional grid view. Give some suggestions about this designs. Thanks in advance.  [image]

Comment: You just need to use UICollectionView and write your custom UICollectionViewLayout. Read the documentation. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use UICollectionView, you can get many examples here [https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=✓&q=grid](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=grid)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you would be interested in trying this controller: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/waterfallcollectionview